# Form Option value?

Tags: php

What I want to do, is to display the quantity to url bar when the form is submitted. What I did wrong? Because right now wont display the value?

[Form to choose quantity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t4s7k.png)

[Display the selected value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zcgYM.png)

```
            <form action="addtocart?quantity=<?php if(isset($_POST['quantity'])){echo $_POST['quantity'];} ?>" method="POST">
            <div>
                <label for="quantity">Quantity</label>
                <select name="quantity" id="quantity">
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <button type ="submit">Add to Cart</button>
        </form>
```

Comment: Change `method="POST"` to `method="GET"` and only set the action to: `action="addtocart"` and the data will be sent as query parameters instead.

Comment: Actually it works. But the thing is, that I want to pass multiple values (such as product id of the product that I am currently looking). And at the end, would look like this: /addtocart?productid=1?quantity=1

Comment: It would look like: `addtocart?productid=1&quantity=1`. When you use `GET`, all inputs you have in the form will be sent in the URL as query parameters so just add those inputs to your form and you're set.